# How to create a script that displays the content of its arguments using line separator?

Tags: linux, awk

I am fairly new to Linux programming and I need to create a script that takes 3 arguments and displays its contents formatted like this:

- Separator Line
- Filename
- Separator Line
- File content
- Separator Line

I know I have to use the "awk" command but I cannot find a way to make it

Comment: Hint: use `$1` to fetch the first argument, `$2` for the 2nd... So if you call the script like `./script.sh "hello" "bye"` you can say `echo "1st=$1, 2nd=$2`, etc.

Comment: You've only given two lines of output, for your three inputs. Can you add a little more detail about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Is the file content an argument, or is it the contents of a file named in the arguments?

Comment: I have managed to fetch the arguments but I need to display their contents like the format mentioned.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `awk` for this?

Comment: @Barmar the arguments are file names

Answer (score 0):

```sh
for file; do
    echo "|"
    echo "$file"
    echo "|"
    cat "$file"
    echo "|"
done
```

Leaving out the `in` clause to `for` is equivalent to:

```
for file in "$@"
```

and loops through the script arguments.

Comment: I am sorry if I confused you. "Separator Line" is supposed to be this symbol: "|"

Comment: Consider that just a placeholder, you can put whatever you want there.

Comment: how can I use this code when I am expecting for the user to provide the files? can I use "$1" instead of "file"?

Comment: The `for` loop is looping over the arguments to the script.

Comment: To clarify, if you don't provide an "in" clause, the `for` command automatically cycles through the script arguments